# CMake/CPack: How to avoid top-level directory in zip files

Tags: cmake, zip, cpack

I'm using cpack to create my zip file of my binaries. Everything works fine, but one thing is ugly. CPack always generate a top-level directory (with the name of the project and some other variables).

Does anybody know how i can tell cpack to get rid of this auto toplevel directory?

CMake: 3.4.x
OS: Win7 x64

Thanks in advance
Tonka

Comment: Does this answer your question? [cpack create zip without creating self named directory inside zip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54332099/cpack-create-zip-without-creating-self-named-directory-inside-zip)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

found the solution myself.

There is a [CPACK_INCLUDE_TOPLEVEL_DIRECTORY](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/variable/CPACK_INCLUDE_TOPLEVEL_DIRECTORY.html) variable.

If it is set to ...

- `ON` (default) you will get a toplevel directory
- `OFF` you will get no toplevel directory