# cpack create zip without creating self named directory inside zip

Tags: c++, cmake, cpack

I'm creating a zip with my target binary and header files that go with it. I'm trying to find a way to get this to work without creating a self-named folder inside the zip, and have the zip simply contain the target binary and header files at its root.

Here's the entire project in a small zip (5k) on dropbox: [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/i7ufecvx57lr2hk/sis_cg_lib.zip?dl=0)

Here's how I build and package:

```
cd Build
cmake ..
make
make package
```

## Version details:

> > cmake --version
>
> cmake version 3.10.2
>
> CMake suite maintained and supported by Kitware (kitware.com/cmake).
>
> > cpack --version
>
> cpack version 3.10.2
>
> CMake suite maintained and supported by Kitware (kitware.com/cmake).
>
> > gcc --version
>
> gcc (Ubuntu 7.3.0-27ubuntu1~18.04) 7.3.0
>   Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
>   This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is > NO
>   warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

## CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.2)
###################################################################### PROJECT
project(sis_cg_lib)
###################################################################### FILES

file(GLOB_RECURSE SIS_CG_LIB_INC "deps/*.h" "deps/*.inl" )
file(GLOB_RECURSE SIS_CG_LIB_SRC "sources/*.cpp" )

###################################################################### TARGET

add_library(SIS_CG_Lib ${SIS_CG_LIB_INC} ${SIS_CG_LIB_SRC})

###################################################################### SETTINGS

target_include_directories(SIS_CG_Lib PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/deps)

###################################################################### PACKAGE

install(DIRECTORY deps/
    DESTINATION deps
)

install(TARGETS SIS_CG_Lib
    ARCHIVE DESTINATION .
)

set(CPACK_OUTPUT_FILE_PREFIX "")
set(CPACK_GENERATOR "ZIP" CACHE STRING "Generators to support. semi-colon delimited list")
include(CPack)
```

## Desired contents of the zip:

```
libSIS_CG_Lib.a
deps/vec3.h
```

## Actual contents of the zip:

```
sis_gc_lib-0.1.1-Linux/libSIS_CG_Lib.a
sis_gc_lib-0.1.1-Linux/deps/vec3.h
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The option I was looking for is called [CPACK_INCLUDE_TOPLEVEL_DIRECTORY](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CPACK_INCLUDE_TOPLEVEL_DIRECTORY.html?highlight=zip)

I added this line to my CMakeLists.txt before `include(CPack)`:

```
set(CPACK_INCLUDE_TOPLEVEL_DIRECTORY OFF)
```